# AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

We're trying to do calendar sync between outlook and our calendar and running into this error

https://snag.gy/o2dtm9.jpg

We've connected hundreds of accounts and never ran into the issue

Comment: You should copy any relevant information from the image into the post itself.  This will help people better understand how to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Please include examples of how you're calling this, not just a screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your screenshot it could be one of the following scenarios:

1. Your Application ID in your web.config does not match the Application ID in your app registration. Double-check that these values are the same.
2. The Reply URL in your portal needs to match the URL of your published application. This can happen if the Reply URL in your app registration is still set to localhost or is set to something other than the main page that you want your users to reach. This can also happen if the homepage URL in the portal is still set to localhost.
3. Your app might be registered in the wrong tenant.

Please see [this documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) for reference. (Ignore the part that says localhost if you are using a published app.)